# Fan/Light combo with Remote. When turned on with switch, the led flash once

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan, led

We have a guest room in our house that has a light/fan combo that is controlled by on switch.

When I turn the switch on and the LEDs are set off, the fan will start to spin, I can hear what sounds like the motor starting up and the LEDs flash one time and then go off. If I set the lights on and turn off the switch, then turn the switch on, the lights work as normal.

The fixutre is rated for the LEDs in question and the one time flicker happens with different bulbs.

I have checked the connections and everything seems tight.

Is there some type of regulator or something that could be going bad? I don't have an age on the fan, it was installed when we moved into the house.

Edit / Update:

Bypassed the remote receiver and the lights work as they should. Seems to be something failing inside the receiver. Leaving lights hardwired to switch as I prefer it this way anyway.

Comment: What make and model is said fan/light combo, and what make and model are the LEDs for that matter)?  Does the flickering happen with incandescent bulbs fitted?

Comment: The Make is a Hunter, model is unknown. I have been trying to locate the exact model.

LEDs tried: Longstar LED L7-A19DEC-9w-30s and and Amazon Basics 9W LED. The amazon Basics don't light up quite as bright as the Longstars during the one second flash.

The fixture is rated for Max 14W CLF of LED, consequently I won't be using incandesants in the fixture.

Comment: Does the fixture not have an incandescent rating at all?

Comment: It has no incandescent rating at all. Just says "Caution - Risk of Fire Max 14 W Type CFL or led"

Comment: Please remove your "update" and post it as an answer. Not only are self-answers acceptable, they're encouraged. Also, it may help someone else who has run into a similar problem in the future, as they'll see that this has an accepted answer and would be more likely to look at this for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Bypassed the remote receiver and the lights work as they should. Seems to be something failing inside the receiver. Leaving lights hardwired to switch as I prefer it this way anyway.